How to import logs from Azure Storage File Share to Log Analytics?
How to import/stream a new line delimited logs (.log) from Azure Storage File Share to Log Analytics Workspace?
My .log file is in format:
2024-04-09 12:09:56|   0.0|  0.0|INFORM|APP 2021.0.0.0 (Build 211111 - linux-x64) 2024-04-09 12:09:56|   0.0|  0.0|INFORM|APP is '/opt/app-2021/'
I tried to "Create a custom log" but failed because schema sample file should be in .json. How properly should I convert the file?

You can use Azure Monitor. It provides a feature called "Log ingestion" which allows you to ingest logs from various sources, including Azure Storage File Share, into Log Analytics Workspace.
However, as far as I know, Azure Monitor currently doesn't directly support ingesting logs from Azure Storage File Share in .log format. Log Analytics expects structured data in JSON format for ingestion. Thus, you'll need to transform your log data into a structured JSON format. As an example to do that in Python:
import json

def logToJson(logEntry):
fields = logEntry.strip().split('|')
logJson = {
    "timestamp": fields[0].strip(),
    "severity": fields[3].strip(),
    "app_version": fields[4].strip(),
    "app_path": fields[5].strip(),
    .
    .
    .
}
return json.dumps(logJson)

